# Tomcat server works, but can not deploy my JSP file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I started a Tomcat server in Eclipse, and I can have access to localhost without problem, this means the server is indeed working. However, weird things happened today, my JSP file does not work any more for some reason, and I can not deploy any JSP file now. 
[successful Tomcat server running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLk1Y.png)

[hello.jsp file does not get deployed now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBwwS.png)

Comment: Maybe you can try removing the app from tomcat (in eclipse), then restart, then try to add and deploy again.

Comment: it turns out someone answered my question, yes, I put the JSP file into the wrong folder. Instead of putting under WebContent, I added under WEB-INF, that's why it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

where you set path for hello.jsp?plz check the location of your hello.jsp.if your hello.jsp exists under WebContent just i shown in image1.you should access like that localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hello.jsp.[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUx5.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpoEr.jpg  but when your jsp file is in other folder of WebContent ,just shown in image2,you should access like that localhost:8080/HelloWorld/jsp/hello.jsp.  [image]

Comment: Yes, you are right, after spending 8h I finally figured that my JSP file was in the wrong folder. Maybe I should delete this post, it is very stupid I know...

Comment: @HongbinSun Don't delete the post. It may help someone else. Especially since you got a answer that helped.